# Don't show search bar on the home page but on all other pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem dealing with Ruby on rails. I have this website http://rescore.io/ and there is a search bar on the top right and in the middle of the page. I want to make it so this top right search bar does not appear on the home page but on every other page, so what i though first was if i can say if current_page = home_page don't display the search bar, but the thing is that i can't actually put it in code. If anyone can help me that would be great.

My code for the search bar is:

```
form action="/movies/search_by_title"
            input name="query" type="text" placeholder="Search movies" /
```

My question is how do i make the condition to check if the page is the home page and tell it not to display the top right search bar only on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want something like

```
<%= render 'search_bar' unless url_for == home_page_path %>
```

Or, if your search bar isn't in a partial:

```
<% unless url_for == home_page_path %>
  <!-- whatever your code is -->
<% end %>
```

It's not exactly semantic but it works.

Comment: Isn't there a way to say it with -if current_page /= home_page_url (which is the actual url for the home page ) if that is how you say is different from. Because i am using ruby slim and that won't work.

Comment: Rails doesn't have a current_page helper, so you won't be able to do it like that. I'm unfamiliar with ruby slim, but you should have have access to all the regular rails stuff, yes? Try:  `- unless url_for == home_page_path` and replace home_page_path with whatever your path helper is for your home page. It's probably `root_path`.

Comment: Alright that works but it moved the search bar on the other pages to the right and i can only see half of it.

Comment: That would probably mean you either put it in the wrong place or there's something messed up with your styles. A conditional isn't going to change your layout.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help i will try and see what i can do about the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a separate layout for the home page and make the search field in the upper right corner of the page be part of the layout, not the page.

In the layout for the main page simply don't include the elements that you don't want displayed there.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Yes but that would take more time than just say if current_page is different from home_page_url then execute the code otherwise don't. Isn't there a way to do it like this? And on the other hand the search bar is not on the actual page but on the navigation bar which is part of the home page.

Comment: I'm recommending that it's a better way to solve the problem, and it doesn't take more than a few minutes.

Comment: OK i understand that but the thing is that the search bar is part of the navigation bar which is a part of the whole website not just the home page.

Comment: If you're trying to DRY up your layouts you can use a partial layout. You can use the content_for (see link from my post) or use various other techniques. But since you are now trying to solve a separate problem (how to make good reuse in the layouts) I'd suggest asking that separately.